# Getting name of input element when passed into function

Tags: jquery, input

How would I get the name of the input element when it's passed into a function? `$(this).prop('name')` returned an empty string.

**Input coming in**

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="selectAll(this)" name="NBTC"/>
```

**Function**

```
function selectAll(source) {
    var sourceName = $(this).prop('name');
}
```

Comment: change $(this) to $(source)

Comment: @SeanT perfect, thanks. Put your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Just use `source.name`  http://jsfiddle.net/bgrjcnwv/

Comment: @Taplar as stated in the original post, that does not work. I was missing the selector syntax around `source` as SeanT pointed out.

Comment: @MKF my fiddle proves that it does work

Comment: @Taplar - I tried it again... you're right, it does work. I wonder if I changed something along the way that allowed it to be valid because I know the first time I tried it, it wasn't working. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Better still, use an unobtrusive jQuery event handler instead of the awful and outdated `on*` attributes. Then `this` will work as you're currently using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `$(this)` to `$(source)` as that's what's being passed in to your function.